# Geography Convert LINESTRING to POLYGON

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How do i convert the closed linestring to a polgyon for Geography  with MS SQL or C#.  I am trying to build this data so I can search the data within the MS SQL database.  When i try to convert the data with the function STGeomFromWKB, it didn't return the right shape.

```
DECLARE @data geography;
 SET @data= 'LINESTRING(145.13527778 13.64166667, 144.74694444 13.47666667, 144.63722222 13.51194444, 144.61944444 13.5875, 144.62337227 13.60962359, 144.62777753 13.63154738, 144.63412072 13.65301205, 144.64235403 13.6738541, 144.65241522 13.69391474, 144.66422807 13.71304108, 144.67770294 13.73108731, 144.69273746 13.74791585, 144.70921729 13.76339835, 144.72701699 13.7774167,144.74600098 13.78986396,144.76602456 13.80064514,144.78693505 13.80967796,144.80857293 13.81689348,144.83077307 13.82223661,144.85336602 13.82566656,144.87617929 13.82715716,144.8990387 13.826697,144.92176971 13.82428962,144.94419878 13.81995338,144.96615467 13.8137214,144.98746983 13.80564125,145.0079816 13.79577461,145.02753354 13.78419678,145.0459766 13.77099612,145.06317023 13.75627335,145.07898353 13.74014079,145.09329617 13.7227215,145.10599934 13.70414829,145.1169966 13.68456278,145.12620454 13.66411424, 145.13355348 13.64295851, 145.13527778 13.64166667)'; 

 --This shape looks like this
```

[image]

```
 select @data, @data.STAsText()

 --Convert to polygon it

DECLARE @Polygon geography  
SET @Polygon =   geography::STGeomFromWKB(  0x01 + 0x03000000 + 0x01000000   + SUBSTRING(@data.STAsBinary(),6,datalength(@data.STAsBinary())),@data.STSrid)  
select @Polygon
```

The result is wrong like below.
    [image: Return wrong shape]

Comment: Your polygon is there, but the scale is WAY off. If you zoom in on the 9 degree by 140 degree quadrant you can see it. It's tiny. As for how to "convert" to a polygon. I believe you can put your LINESTRING values wrapped in POLYGON instead and it will return the result. Try it out. Like this `SET @data= geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON(( ...))', 4326);` I can't paste the whole string in a comment because it's way too long but put your values in the ellipses and you will see.

Answer (score 3):

If you change that very last line to

```
select @Polygon.ReorientObject();
```

I think you'll find the desired result. Your linestring has what is called a ring orientation problem. The order in which you specify the points is important. As defined, the polygon is the entire globe *minus* the intended polygon. By calling `ReorientObject()` on the polygon, it, well… reorients the object.

Comment: Thanks so much ReorientObject is what i need, i can't believe MS SQL doesn't do that by it self. Now i have to regenerate the data before insert into the database.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult question to answer because you are getting the expected results, but the question asks how to convert a `LINESTRING` to a `POLYGON`. This answer will use a `REPLACE` but surely it can be done other ways (such as the method you tried). Additionally, we will add a bit of "unnecessary" code to show the methodology. This is based on the assumption that the source values are in a closed `LINESTRING` format.

See this set of queries:

```
DECLARE @predata varchar(MAX) = 'LINESTRING(145.13527778 13.64166667, 144.74694444 13.47666667, 144.63722222 13.51194444, 144.61944444 13.5875, 144.62337227 13.60962359, 144.62777753 13.63154738, 144.63412072 13.65301205, 144.64235403 13.6738541, 144.65241522 13.69391474, 144.66422807 13.71304108, 144.67770294 13.73108731, 144.69273746 13.74791585, 144.70921729 13.76339835, 144.72701699 13.7774167,144.74600098 13.78986396,144.76602456 13.80064514,144.78693505 13.80967796,144.80857293 13.81689348,144.83077307 13.82223661,144.85336602 13.82566656,144.87617929 13.82715716,144.8990387 13.826697,144.92176971 13.82428962,144.94419878 13.81995338,144.96615467 13.8137214,144.98746983 13.80564125,145.0079816 13.79577461,145.02753354 13.78419678,145.0459766 13.77099612,145.06317023 13.75627335,145.07898353 13.74014079,145.09329617 13.7227215,145.10599934 13.70414829,145.1169966 13.68456278,145.12620454 13.66411424, 145.13355348 13.64295851, 145.13527778 13.64166667)';
DECLARE @data geography;
DECLARE @linestring geography = @predata;
DECLARE @srid int;
SET @predata = REPLACE(@predata, 'LINESTRING', 'POLYGON(') + ')';
SELECT @predata AS PolygonString
SET @data = geography::STGeomFromText(@predata, @linestring.STSrid);
SELECT @data AS GeographyPolygon
```

After declaring the variables, I did a simple `REPLACE` on the string/varchar representation of the `LINESTRING` to turn it to a `POLYGON`.

```
SET @predata = REPLACE(@predata, 'LINESTRING', 'POLYGON(') + ')';
```

And the result:

```
PolygonString
POLYGON((145.13527778 13.64166667, 144.74694444 13.47666667, 144.63722222 13.51194444, 144.61944444 13.5875, 144.62337227 13.60962359, 144.62777753 13.63154738, 144.63412072 13.65301205, 144.64235403 13.6738541, 144.65241522 13.69391474, 144.66422807 13.71304108, 144.67770294 13.73108731, 144.69273746 13.74791585, 144.70921729 13.76339835, 144.72701699 13.7774167,144.74600098 13.78986396,144.76602456 13.80064514,144.78693505 13.80967796,144.80857293 13.81689348,144.83077307 13.82223661,144.85336602 13.82566656,144.87617929 13.82715716,144.8990387 13.826697,144.92176971 13.82428962,144.94419878 13.81995338,144.96615467 13.8137214,144.98746983 13.80564125,145.0079816 13.79577461,145.02753354 13.78419678,145.0459766 13.77099612,145.06317023 13.75627335,145.07898353 13.74014079,145.09329617 13.7227215,145.10599934 13.70414829,145.1169966 13.68456278,145.12620454 13.66411424, 145.13355348 13.64295851, 145.13527778 13.64166667))
```

After we have a valid `POLYGON` string value with a `+` string concatenation for the final parenthesis, we can pass it to the `STGeomFromText` function as such:

```
SET @data =  geography::STGeomFromText(@predata, @linestring.STSrid);
```

Finally, by selecting the geography type `@data` variable we arrive at the Spatial result.

```
SELECT @data AS GeographyPolygon
```

Which is the same polygon that you have displayed. The scale is very different than the scale of the `LINESTRING` value as it's placed on a full geography plane representation of SRID 4326. The definition of such:

http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/

Since the projected bounds of SRID 4326 are:

> Projected Bounds: -180.0000, -90.0000, 180.0000, 90.0000

This means the scale of the results is *massive* compared to the initial `LINESTRING`. If you zoom in on the 9°-18° by 140°-160° quadrants, you will see the polygon.

Answer (score 0):

The ReorientObject is 50% of the problem. We only need to do this if the EnvelopeAngle is under 90 degree.

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Fixing ring orientation problem By calling ReorientObject() for all any shapes
        /// Shape must be reposition before insert into the database otherwise you have the wrong result especially with the polygon
        /// SQL Script example
        //        DECLARE @Polygon geography;
        //SET @Polygon = 'POLYGON((145.13527778 13.64166667, 144.74694444 13.47666667, 144.63722222 13.51194444, 144.61944444 13.5875, 144.62337227 13.60962359, 144.62777753 13.63154738, 144.63412072 13.65301205, 144.64235403 13.6738541, 144.65241522 13.69391474, 144.66422807 13.71304108, 144.67770294 13.73108731, 144.69273746 13.74791585, 144.70921729 13.76339835, 144.72701699 13.7774167,144.74600098 13.78986396,144.76602456 13.80064514,144.78693505 13.80967796,144.80857293 13.81689348,144.83077307 13.82223661,144.85336602 13.82566656,144.87617929 13.82715716,144.8990387 13.826697,144.92176971 13.82428962,144.94419878 13.81995338,144.96615467 13.8137214,144.98746983 13.80564125,145.0079816 13.79577461,145.02753354 13.78419678,145.0459766 13.77099612,145.06317023 13.75627335,145.07898353 13.74014079,145.09329617 13.7227215,145.10599934 13.70414829,145.1169966 13.68456278,145.12620454 13.66411424, 145.13355348 13.64295851, 145.13527778 13.64166667))'; 
        // --This shape looks like this, you have to zoom in to see, it is really small
        //select @Polygon, 'error here' as ErrorHere

        //set @Polygon=@Polygon.ReorientObject();
        //select @Polygon;

        //--Only convert if the EnvelopeAngle> 90
        //select 
        //case when @Polygon.EnvelopeAngle() > 90 then
        //@Polygon.ReorientObject()
        //  else
        //   @Polygon
        //end  

        //--Do not duplicate ReorientObject it will cost error like below
        //set @Polygon = @Polygon.ReorientObject();
        //        select @Polygon;

        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dataPoints">Example POLYGON((145.13527778 13.64166667, 144.74694444 13.47666667, 144.63722222 13.51194444, 144.61944444 13.5875, 144.62337227 13.60962359, 144.62777753 13.63154738, 144.63412072 13.65301205, 144.64235403 13.6738541, 144.65241522 13.69391474, 144.66422807 13.71304108, 144.67770294 13.73108731, 144.69273746 13.74791585, 144.70921729 13.76339835, 144.72701699 13.7774167,144.74600098 13.78986396,144.76602456 13.80064514,144.78693505 13.80967796,144.80857293 13.81689348,144.83077307 13.82223661,144.85336602 13.82566656,144.87617929 13.82715716,144.8990387 13.826697,144.92176971 13.82428962,144.94419878 13.81995338,144.96615467 13.8137214,144.98746983 13.80564125,145.0079816 13.79577461,145.02753354 13.78419678,145.0459766 13.77099612,145.06317023 13.75627335,145.07898353 13.74014079,145.09329617 13.7227215,145.10599934 13.70414829,145.1169966 13.68456278,145.12620454 13.66411424, 145.13355348 13.64295851, 145.13527778 13.64166667))</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string ReorientObject(string dataPoints)
        {
            //Convert to DbGeography
            DbGeography newGeography = DbGeography.FromText(dataPoints.ToString(), 4326);

            //Fixing ring orientation problem By calling ReorientObject() on the polygon
            SqlGeography parseData = SqlGeography.Parse(dataPoints);
            if (parseData.EnvelopeAngle() > 90)
            {
                parseData= parseData.ReorientObject();
            }
            //Take the new reposition of the poing
            dataPoints = DbGeography.FromText(parseData.ToString(), 4326).AsText();
            return dataPoints;
        }
```